# Valid DTD in XML

Tags: xml, dtd

How is xml1 & 2 not fitting in the DTD? I find the elements (*: zero or more; +: at least once; ?: optional, at most once) still fit since 'elm1' and 'eml2' appeared once respectively. How should I change the DTD if not?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE root[
<!ELEMENT root (elm1*,elm2+)>
<!ELEMENT elm1 (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT elm2 (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

XML 1

```
<root>
<elm1>Blobby</elm1>
</root>
```

XML 2

```
<root>
<elm2>Blobby</elm2>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would expect "XML 2" to validate but not "XML 1" because your declaration for root elements

```
  <!ELEMENT root (elm1*,elm2+)>
```

is basically stating "root may have 0 or more **elm1** children and must have at least 1 or more **elm2** children".

You probably want this?

```
<!ELEMENT root (elm1*,elm2*)>
```

Comment: _I would expect "XML 1" to validate but not "XML 2"_ - I think you have that backwards. Also might be helpful to clarify that `elm2` must come after `elm1`. Everything else looks good. +1

Comment: I think so. Thanks! Can they be (elm1?, eml2?) as they don't have subchild?

Comment: @zitameoba having (sub-)children or not is independent of being marked with ? or * as ocurrence indicator:  `elm1?` means the content model accepts zero or one `elm1` elements at this point, `elm2*` that it accepts zero or more.

Comment: Thanks for your input @DanielHaley.